# CRON Jobs for order emails

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

the issue I am facing is that order emails not working on my magento store. I installed AOE scheduler but I am getting this issue

***No heartbeat task found. Check if cron is configured correctly.***

Though I have set the settings on cpanel
[image]

and AOE scheduler settings on magento
[image]

I am getting this email every second

```
Available actions: 
    --action listAllCodes
    --action lastRun --code <code> [--secondsFromNow]   Get the timestamp of the last successful run of a job for a given code
    --action scheduleNow --code <code>  Schedule a job to be executed as soon as possible
    --action runNow --code <code> [--tryLock] [--force]         Run a job directly
    --action wait [--timout <timeout=60>]               Active wait until no schedules are running.
    --action flushSchedules --mode (future|all)         Flush schedules.
    --action listAllRunningSchedules
    --action killAll
    --action watchdog
    --action cron --mode (always|default) [--includeJobs <comma separated list of jobs>] [--excludeJobs <comma separated list of jobs>] [--includeGroups <comma separated list of groups>] [--excludeGroups <comma separated list of groups>]
```

I am stuck I dont know how to resolve this issue, please help

Comment: First I would change "Heartbeat task schedule (cron syntax)" to `0 * * * *` to not get spammed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest changing the settings "Generate Schedules Every" and "Schedule Ahead For" back to their defaults

```
Generate Schedules Every 15
Schedule Ahead For 20
```

Also the first line calling cron.php is not needed if you have the other two.

According to a similar sounding issue on the Magento forum [here](https://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/Setup-Cpanel-Cron-Command-for-AOE-Scheduler/td-p/37683) what Vaishal recommended above (changing your PATH to include the path to the php binary sounds like a good approach).

I suggest trying out these commands from a command prompt fist via SSH if you can to make sure it works first. And then enter it into the cron configuration.

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin" && /bin/bash /path/to/scheduler_cron.sh --mode always
```

Overall it sounds like what you are using is correct however due to some restrictions placed upon you by your hosting company this is not working. So would suggest getting in touch with your hosting company's technical support to understand where the command line parameters are not passed along correctly.

Comment: Can you guide me, where I want to set my PATH variable?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like PATH variable is set somehow different in jailshelled cron environment. So I suppose different php binary is used.
You can ssh to your cPanel account and set PATH in your crontab.

So crontab should start like:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/cpanel/composer/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/home/username/.local/bin:/home/username/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set direct `root > cron.php` file for cron.

Secondly, you can use an extension `SMTP Pro Email`. There is an option to send email without any queue. Extension link is below.

[SMTP Pro Extension to send email without queue(without cron)](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html)

[image]

Comment: I have used this extension SMTP Pro Extension to send email without queue(without cron), still not working

Comment: did you have check it by seting `cron.php` for cron through capnel.